# How to Set up MongoDB with Graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I have read quite a few implementations about connecting MongoDB with graphql and consuming / querying the data. I even got to the point where I got one working , but I couldn't filter or limit records.

Then I read this https://blog.solutotlv.com/graphql-to-mongodb-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-generated-query-apis/ and it seems like exactly what I want. I'm a bit of a newbie with Node.js , but I cannot figure out how to actually create a graphql server from this post.

There is a whole lot of "this and that" , but no linear step-by-step instructions so I'm a bit lost.

Any help offered is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The mainly difference between a REST app and GraphQL app essentially is not about support databases in different ways, but to manage requests in different ways. So, if you are doing an express app, the only difference is about the requests: you need to bind the graphql queries to the DB queries like findOne, findAll and get, and the graphql resolvers to your DB persistance operations such update, delete and create.

In [this](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/creating-a-graphql-server-with-node-js-and-express-f6dddc5320e1) tutorial for example, the writer uses an fake collection from an array, and a function to get this array or some object inside on it. In your case, is just about change where the data is stored: MongoDB instead an array. If you already have some REST API with mongoDB, kind it will work at the same way on the DB part.